# Python script executes but unable to hear sound which it is playing

Tags: python, libvlc

I am using libvlc python binding to play a music file.my code is as follows:

```
import vlc
instance = vlc.Instance()

#Create a MediaPlayer with the default instance
player = instance.media_player_new()

#Load the media file
media = instance.media_new('01.DONT CARE.mp3')

#Add the media to the player
player.set_media(media)

try:
    player.play()
except Exception, e:
    raise e
```

The script executes successfully but I am unable to hear anything. If the code is executed line by line then it works correctly and I am able to hear the sound.Any idea on what might be wrong?

Comment: If you add a call to [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html) after `player.play()`, do you hear the sound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason it is not being played is because `player.play()` is asynchronous. So when the script exits, it kills the process and stops the media straight away. Try add a `time.sleep(10)` and see does it play.

Note: Don't forget to `import time` at the top.

The reason that it would be working as you type it in line by line is because it isn't exiting the python program.